# Arithmetic of quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I was wondering whether for a ring $R$ and two elements $a,b$ that $R/(a,b)$ is isomorphic to $(R/(a))/(b)$ (with the parenthesis representing the smallest ideal containing the respective element/s).

I have seen this trick applied to polynomial rings on multiple occations.

Thank you

Comment: Yes they are isomorphic. Just take the identity map on $R$ and project it to a map between these two quotient rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Third Isomorphism Theorem tells you that for a ring $R$, and ideals $I\leq K\leq R$, you have that $K/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$ and that
$$\frac{R/I}{K/I}\cong \frac{R}{K}.$$
We can apply this to you situation by taking $I=(b)$, $J=(a)$, and $K=I+J=(a,b)$.

Note that the smallest ideal containing $b+(a)$ in $R/(a)$ is in fact the ideal $(b)+(a)=(a,b)+(a)=K/(a)$. Thus, you are asking whether 
$\frac{R/(a)}{K/(a)}$ is isomorphic to $R/K$. And then the Third Isomorphism Theorem tells you immediately that the answer is “yes”.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that it should follow easily from the Isomorphism Theorem. However, how do you realize the last part about the ideal generated by $ b $ in the quotient ring?

Comment: @Deracless: because the ideals of the quotient correspond to the ideals of $R$ that contain $(a)$, so you are looking for the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains both $a$ and $b$.